# How to Uninstall Linux Mint 14 From Windows XP Without CD

Tags: linux, windows-xp, linux-mint, uninstall, grub2

This is kind of a follow up to a question I just asked, but... I'm planning to install Linux Mint 14 in a dual boot with my existing Windows XP setup, but I want to make sure I know how to uninstall it first, just in case the need arises. I've heard you need an installation CD to restore the NTLDR or MBR or whatever Windows XP uses, but my laptop was a gift I got 5 years ago, and I don't think it came with a CD. So in that case, what would I do? Is there a standard method for this sort of thing?

Comment: There are ways to restore the XP bootloader from Linux, or using a WinPE-based CD such as Hiren's, which the article linked to below mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine, as there are many ways to do this and you don't need the original installation disc. Have a quick look at this article: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Comment: Might want to include the major points here rather than just posting a link.

Comment: I just did not really have the time when I wrote it.